# How to find a point(x,y) inside a irregular polygon using Oracle10g Spatial function or any other API

Tags: oracle10g, geometry, gis, autocad, geotools

I am very new in working with GIS or geometry data. I have geometry data (polygon) in oracle10g database. Is there any Spatial function to find a point inside that polygon. If not then any tool like geotools for .Net or any other API can help me. The polygon can have hole inside it. So point must be in a polygon area.

Thanks in advance for your help

Naym

Comment: Total internal angle, dot product, intersection point  all spring to mind......

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Oracle Locator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B10826_01/sdo_locator.htm)? The query syntax is awful to read, but it is capable of doing "is point in polygon" queries. You'll need to create a spatial index column on any table that you want to run a spatial query against. Reading the documentation is a must, because it is a pain to get working initially.